# Why C++ runs a little slower compared to Java when creating unique ID?

Tags: java, c++

I wrote the same algorithm in C++ and Java and I noticed that the C++ version is a little slower than Java's on my Mac. I compile the Java version with default settings with JIT on. And the C++ version with Release option with CMake. Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// Snow Flake
static const unsigned int randomNumberShiftBits = 12;
static const unsigned int randomNumberMask = (1u << randomNumberShiftBits) - 1;
static const unsigned int machineNumberShiftBits = 5;
static const unsigned int machineNumberMask = (1u << machineNumberShiftBits) - 1;
static const unsigned int dataCenterNumberShiftBits = 5;
static const unsigned int dataCenterNumberMask = (1u << dataCenterNumberShiftBits)-1;
static const unsigned int dateTimeShiftBits = 41;
static const unsigned long long dateTimeMask = (1ull << dateTimeShiftBits) - 1;

static std::atomic_uint snowFlakeId = 0;
static unsigned long long lastTimeStamp = 0;
static unsigned int DataCenterID=1;
static unsigned int MachineID=1;


std::int64_t get() {
    auto current = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    if (current != lastTimeStamp) {
        snowFlakeId = 0;
        lastTimeStamp = current;
    }
    unsigned long long id = 0;
    // Datetime part
    id |= static_cast<unsigned long long>(static_cast<unsigned long long>(current) & dateTimeMask);

    // DataCenter Part
    id <<= dataCenterNumberShiftBits;
    id |= static_cast<uint>(static_cast<uint>(DataCenterID)&dataCenterNumberMask);

    // Machine Part
    id <<= machineNumberShiftBits;
    id |= static_cast<uint>(static_cast<uint>(MachineID)&machineNumberMask);

    // Random Number Part
    id <<= randomNumberShiftBits;
    id |= static_cast<uint>(snowFlakeId&randomNumberMask);

    snowFlakeId++;
    return id;
}

int main() {
    for (int out = 0; out < 10; out++) {
        auto start = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
            get();
        }
        auto end = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
                std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
        std::cout << (end - start) << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The Java code is exactly the same.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class Test {

    static int randomNumberShiftBits = 12;
    static int randomNumberMask = (1 << randomNumberShiftBits) - 1;
    static int machineNumberShiftBits = 5;
    static int machineNumberMask = (1 << machineNumberShiftBits) - 1;
    static int dataCenterNumberShiftBits = 5;
    static int dataCenterNumberMask = (1 << dataCenterNumberShiftBits) - 1;
    static int dateTimeShiftBits = 41;
    static long dateTimeMask = (1L << dateTimeShiftBits)-1;

    static AtomicInteger snowFlakeId = new AtomicInteger(0);
    static long lastTimeStamp = 0;
    static int DataCenterID = 1;
    static int MachineID = 1;

    public static long get() {
        var current = System.currentTimeMillis();

        if (current != lastTimeStamp) {
            snowFlakeId.set(0);
            lastTimeStamp=current;
        }

        long id = 0;

        id |= current&dateTimeMask;

        id <<= dataCenterNumberShiftBits;
        id |= DataCenterID&dataCenterNumberMask;

        id <<= machineNumberShiftBits;
        id |= MachineID&machineNumberMask;

        id <<= randomNumberShiftBits;
        id |= snowFlakeId.get() & randomNumberMask;

        snowFlakeId.incrementAndGet();
        return id;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int out = 0; out < 10; out++) {
            var start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
                get();
            }
            var end = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println(end - start);
        }
    }
}
```

C++ needs 36 seconds to finish one loop on my computer while Java only need 29 seconds. I just wonder why there is such difference and what JVM does to make this happen.

When I tried to store all the result in an array with enough memory (I also changed 1000000000 to 100000000), with `ArrayList<Long>` in Java and `std::vector<int64_t>` in C++, the result changed. And this time C++ is 2 times faster than Java and only uses 800MB while Java uses 6GB according to Activity Monitor. I guess that JVM does some optimization when the result of `get` is ignored so that Java runs faster than C++. But when the result is stored. The optimization is gone. As for the memory, I guess it's because GC is not working when there is still enough memory available.

The code has a bug when running in parallel that same ID could be generated. But it's not related to the question.

**Update**

Someone mentioned that the it might be the reason of getting the current timestamp. I replaced that line with assigning a fixed number `164635438` to current. And both are much faster but Java version is still faster than C++ version. With fixed number, Java uses (in millionsecond):

```
5479
6289
6306
6267
6290
6284
6280
6285
6278
6406
```

while C++ uses (in millionsecond):

```
7586
7499
7533
7637
7711
7638
7634
7607
7575
7538
```

**Conclusion**

After several times of trying, I found that JVM optimized the code because the return value is ignored while C++ didn't do much optimization like Java did. When I store the return value in one variable, and print that variable out outside the timer area. C++ and Java have the same time cost. When I remove the code that gets the current timestamp and using a fixed number instead. C++ is about 30% faster than Java.

Comment: Do `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` have the same accuracy?

Comment: Try removing all the bitwise operations and just call system_clock::now versus System.currentTimeMillis. it may be that the clock queryig is faster in Java. Just a guess. @Jacob when you're dealing with a several seconds difference, the milliseconds accuracy is of no importance.

Comment: p.s. you are using the atomic integer value in a different statement than the one where you increment it. So that is not doing what you think it's doing.

Comment: @PatrickParker Yeah but the result is still the same when I use just `unsigned long long` for C++ and `long` for Java rather than atomic variable.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. My "p.s." about the atomic integer was not related to speed but rather correctness.

Comment: @PatrickParker Ahh yeah my mistake and sorry for that. But I tried to remove all the std library difference and only keep the basic syntax. Java is still faster than C++. wierd.

Comment: All questions regarding C++ benchmarks are useless unless one provides a concrete compiler setup used to compile the code. What is your compiler? What optimisations flags did you feed it? What is your build type (debug / release - you stated it, good)? JVM performs optimisations on the resulting byte code automatically, but unless you specify concrete optimisations flags, C++ compilers won't do much of them.